# Convert transparent MOV to GIF

Tags: ffmpeg

I currently have a transparent mov file.  I am trying to convert it to a GIF, and am using the command

```
ffmpeg -i file.mov file.gif
```

But the resulting GIF is not transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use additional option to set the palette:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mov -f gif -lavfi split[v],palettegen,[v]paletteuse file.gif
```